# Duplicate item in document library when you edit MS Word file in Word Online with .doc format

Tags: sharepoint-online

Create one MS Word file in 97-2003 file format i.e. .doc format file. Upload it to Office 365 Document Library. Try to modify the file using Word Online in browser. It will prompt you to convert the file. When you convert the file it will create duplicate entry in the document library with extension of new file .docx.

I required to restrict duplicate entry of the file in document library. Kindly suggest a way to achieve this.